# Selecionando Row em um DataGrid a partir de uma pesquisa. C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Boa tarde Galera,
Alguém tem um código onde eu consiga Selecionar uma `Row` em um `DataGrid`, a partir de uma pesquisa ?

Onde eu realciono meu `Button_Click` a um `TextBox` com um determinado valor, fazendo a busca no `DataGridView`, assim selecionando a `Row` referente àquele valor do `TextBox`.

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você tem um botão, e um textbox, onde você entra com algum valor, e ao clicar no botão vc quer que ele percorra o datagrid e se encontrar a linha, por exemplo pinte ela de vermelho e isso? seja mais especifico na sua pergunta, se possivel adicione prints, e parte do codigo

Comment: @ThomasErichPimentel exatamente isso.
Um comando que busque no DataGrid uma linha com o valor que eu determinei, e quando o comando encontrar, selecione esta linda.

Comment: Acho que a resposta do @zekk ja resolveu seu problema ne?

Comment: Rodando perfeitamente !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode percorrer os `rows` do `DataGrid` e comparar os valores com o texto do `TextBox`.

```
string pesquisar = textBox1.Text.ToLower();

dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (row.Cells["NomeDaColuna"].Value != null)
    {
        if (row.Cells["NomeDaColuna"].Value.ToString().ToLower().Equals(pesquisar))
        {
            row.Selected = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, este comando está funcionando parcialmente, quando a execução chega no 2º `if` para valorar a int rowIndex, ele não entra na chave.

Comment: @MaurícioSanches Você colocou o nome da coluna correta? outra coisa, o texto do `textbox` tem que ser **exato**.

Comment: Ok! está correto agora, o problema era eu que não estava considerando Maiusculos e Minusculos. está rodando certo agora.

Comment: @MaurícioSanches Você pode usar o método [`ToLower`](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolower) em ambas as *strings* e compará-las, sobre o segundo problema, antes de fazer a pesquisa, use: `DataGridView1.ClearSelection();`.